# problem with routing?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a problem with my routing in mvc.

I have this http://localhost:1138/Administration

this show the index of Administration controller

I have here two tab: User, MemberVIP, with his controller UserController and MemberController.

When I go to User my route is this http://localhost:1138/User but I want this
http://localhost:1138/Administration/User  the same with MemberVip

any idea!!

Thanks

Comment: Areas would be the best choice for this...Check this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Cybernate mentioned, Areas are really the best way to deal with this. If you absolutely insisted, you could hack it with a special route entry for those sub routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "AdminUserRoute",
            "Administration/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Administration", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Be sure that you position this in your list of routes so that it doesn't inadvertently catch proper routes on other URLs. You might want to try out Phil Haack's RouteDebugger (available on NuGet).